# Old unknown database

Tags: database

I got this work assignment from my boss where I shall try to get information from an old database. The thing is, we know nothing about it. We hope it is some known format and not something the developer made himself.

It comes standalone with an application (unknown language) and seems to be a mix of file types. In one folder there are, for example:

MISCINFO.BRG (27 531 kb)
MISCINFO.IDX (264 kb)
MISCINFO.LOG (30 422 kb)

In another folder where there are a bunch of VIS-files.

I don't really know where to start. I need some driver to access these files, preferbly by ODBC or just by open them somehow.

Comment: My initial guess would be that the .LOG is a log file and the .IDX is an index, like in the DBase days; so I would concentrate on the BRG. Have you tried opening the BRG? Is it text or binary? (you'd be surprised at old databases storing things as text); either way, what are the first couple of lines of that file (you might need to use an hex editor)?

Comment: Do you have access to a Linux box? Have you tried running "file MISCINFO.BRG"?

Comment: Whats the context of the database? Some internal stuff or from a client? If its a client, what kind of business are they in?

Comment: Does the application in question come with any dll files? If so what are they called?

Comment: The data is from an old medical system. We want to be able to convert/transfer the data to a new system with an SQL database.

Comment: Did you have any luck on converting these files? I'm having the same issue myself. @user2052501

Answer (score 2):

.brg could be a bridge file mentioned here:

http://www.recital.com/adminDBS.htm

Answer (score 1):

The application in question comes with some DLL files. One of them is DATABASE.DLL, which contains a couple of names of people in plain text. I've searched some names on Google and found a Delphi programmer which I've contacted and waiting reply from. I've verified Delphi as the application language with some other sources.

According to Dependency Walker the DATABASE.DLL contains some functions for open/close a connection and fetching, updating and deleting data. Some functions indicates the DLL to be custom made. Perhaps I can use the same DLL.

Dependecy Walker only shows exported functions and not anything about parameters. Some files it can't open at all because they are 16-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best way to go is to look at what software is known to use files with those extensions. `LOG` isn't much use, but `BRG`, `VIS` and `IDX` are reasonably rare.

**[VIS files](http://filext.com/file-extension/VIS)**:

- Picture File
- StudioPro 3D File
- Vision Executive (Report) by Lasata Software
- VISkompakt (Objects Description File) by PDV-Systeme GmbH
- Vista Graphics

**BRG files**:

The only reference I can find is for [Age of Mythology](http://aom.heavengames.com/cgi-bin/forums/display.cgi?action=ct&f=1,20502,,all), which seems unlikely.

**[IDX files](http://filext.com/file-extension/IDX)**:

- AOL (Temporary Internet Mail File)
- ArcView (Geocoding Index For Read-Only Datasets) by ESRI
- Ca Visual Objects Platform for Developer (CAVO) (Index File) by CA
- Clip Gallery 1.x (Index) by Microsoft Corporation
- Complete Works (Index File) by Toplevel Computing
- Corel QuickFinder Information
- FAX File
- FoxPro (Index) by Microsoft Corporation
- ICQ (Index) by ICQ Inc.
- Java (Applet Cache Index) by Sun Microsystems, Inc.
- LaTeX Index
- NoX
- Outlook Express (Mailbox Index) by Microsoft Corporation
- Pro/ENGINEER (Index File) by PTC
- RCA/Lyra Handheld MP3 Player (Database Index) by RCA
- Symantec Q&A (Relational Database Index File) by Symantec Corporation
- VSFilter (Index File)

Since none of those look that hopeful (there are no products I can see in the lists for VIS files and IDX files), I think unfortunately your hopes that it's not a custom format seem likely to be in vain.

Comment: I'm very positive the BRG file is the database and the key file to investigate. The IDX most likely is just index data; which means that the BRG is possible easy to inspect (if the index data is kept separately, then the database has a potential to not be so hard).

Comment: just FYI, the old MicroFocus Object COBOL system used to use .idx for their ISAM files. Not relevant in this context, but you can add it to the list!

Comment: Try dropping the BRG on a linux box and running strings on it - it might get you *some* data out. Important thing is that it MIGHT have fixed length records, so you could then write some tool to import into another format.

Comment: There is also reference to BRG in the DB2 help. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql02521w.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the 'file' on those files on a linux system. File ignores the file extension, it actually examines the file to identify it.
So copy the files to a linux machine and execute the following command in a terminal window:

Usage:

```
$ cd my_directory_with_unknownfiles
$ file *
```